# How can I change the Color of the SECONDARY toolbar in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigationbar

Currently I set the Primary toolbar background color with this code in the App.xaml.cs class:

```
//SET PRIMARY TOOLBAR COLOR
Current.Resources = new ResourceDictionary ();
Color xamarin_color = Color.FromHex ("#3498db");            
var navigationStyle = new Style (typeof (NavigationPage));
var barBackgroundColorSetter = new Setter { Property = NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColorProperty, Value = xamarin_color };          
navigationStyle.Setters.Add (barBackgroundColorSetter);         
Current.Resources.Add (navigationStyle);
```

The navigationPage PRIMARY toolbar changes its color correctly. But the SECONDARY toolbar doesn't change its default color (gray), and I cannot find any method or property to change it.
How can I change the background color of the secondary toolbar?

Comment: Are you talking about where the toolbar where the ToolbarItems are? Which version of Forms are you using? And are you trying to do this for a specific platform?

Comment: I'm talking about the secondary toolbar, on all platforms. The one that you enable with the Order attribute:
<ToolbarItem Icon="icon1.png"></ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="icon2.png"></ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="icon3.png" Order="Secondary" Text="Task3"></ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="icon4.png" Order="Secondary" Text="Task4"></ToolbarItem>

Comment: @EmanueleSabetta please check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71771456/xamarin-ios-does-not-paint-secondary-toolbar-in-the-requested-color